# Styles other than steam suited for use of Northern Brewer hops

Tags: hops, recipe-formulation

So I have a one pound bag of northern brewer hops (along with about a half pound left of amarillos).  Any suggestions for a recipe or style?  I'm typically pretty boring, love to brew APA's, IPA's (though I do have a winter warmer going along with a Gose)...also have limited temp control.

Anyone have any luck using Northern Brewers in a spring/summer blonde?  Maybe a porter or an American variation on an ESB?  Never brewed me one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Northern brewer makes a fine bittering hop for almost any style. The alpha acid content is not a high as some more modern varieties, but high enough that you can reach a reasonable IBU target with just an ounce or two.

I've also used Northern Brewer for wheat beers -- 3/4 oz for a five gallon batch, boil for 60 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The [Hop Union variety handbook](http://hopunion.com/17_HopVarietyHandbook.cfm?p3=open) says that Northern Brewer hops are good in 'All English-styles especially Porter." Kolsch and Helles are also suggested, but maybe not the best choice if you have limited temp control.

Looking at Hopville, there are [currently 6466 recipes](http://hopville.com/brewing-ingredients/hop/211/northern-brewer) that use Northern Brewer hops. I didn't go through all 6000, but I see a huge variety of styles, everything from APA to RIS.

Comment: been brewing for almost 3 years, and have never come across that resource.  Thanks!